# If $f(0,0) = f(\infty,0)=f(0,\infty) = 1$, but $f(\infty,\infty) = 0$, then what is $f(a,b)$?

Tags: functions, puzzle, functional-equations, elementary-functions

> $f(a,b)=1$ if both $a$ and $b$ are 0, or if one of them is infinity and the other zero. However $f(\infty,\infty)=0$. What is $f(a,b)$?

I tried using exponentials, $f(a,b)=\exp(-a)+\exp(-b)$, but could not satisfy all constraints.

Comment: Maybe a good fit for [puzzlingSE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function $f(a,b)$ that's *continuous* on $\mathbb{R}^2$, with values for infinite $a$ and/or $b$ defined via appropriate limits, we could make a small adjustment to your sum of exponentials:

> $$f(a,b) = \frac{e^{-a} + e^{-b}}{1+e^{-a}\,e^{-b}}$$

We have 
$$f(a,0) \;\equiv\; 1 \;\equiv\; f(0,b)$$
for all finite $a$ and $b$, hence 
$$f(\infty,0) := \lim_{a\to\infty}f(a,0) = 1 = \lim_{b\to\infty} f(0,b) =: f(0,\infty)$$
Also,
$$f(\infty,\infty) := \lim_{a\to\infty,\;b\to\infty}f(a,b) = 0$$

---

**Note.** You *can* simplify this to
$$f(a,b) = \frac{e^a + e^b}{1 + e^{a+b}}$$
but the limiting behavior becomes slightly less evident.

Answer (score 3):

Your statement is a fine definition of a function.  The domain is $\{0,\infty\} \times \{0,\infty\}$ and the range is $\{0,1\}$.  What is the problem?  If the domain is supposed to be $[0,\infty] \times [0,\infty]$ you can define $f(a,b)$ on the rest of the domain however you want.  Maybe it is $\pi$.

Comment: It must be $\tau$, certainly not $\pi$. :D

Answer (score 2):

> $f(a,b) = 1 - \frac{a b}{(a+1)(b+1)}$

We could use some construct like $g(a, b) = 1 - a b$, in which we get $g(0,0) = g(1,0) = g(0,1) = 1$ and $g(1,1) = 0$.

So, we need to find a function that would make $0$s into $0$s, and $\infty$s into $1$s and form a composition with $g$.

One such function is $h(x) = \frac{x}{x + 1}$.

Forming a composition, we get: $f(a,b) = 1 - \frac{a b}{(a+1)(b+1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. How about:
$$f(x)=\max(e^{-a},e^{-b})$$
The usage of the maximum makes $f(0,0)=1$, not 2 as would arise with your try of $e^{-a}+e^{-b}$. All other constraints remain the same.